# React - Problema mostrando un dato en un input

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Estoy recuperando datos de una acción en un reducer mediante useEffect y me sale bien, se recupera perfectamente. El problema está en cuando quiero mostrar ese dato dentro de un input como un value.
El uso de ID:{id_tipo} se muestra siempre excepto dentro del input.

```
            const storageidtipo = useSelector((store) => store.atributos.storidtipo);
            const initEvent = { id_tipo: storageidtipo }; //declaro el estado inicial

            const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initEvent);
            const { id_tipo } = formValues;

            const onChangeInput = ({ target }) => { //en el input tengo esto
                setFormValues({ ...formValues, [target.name]: target.value });
            };
            const establecerDatos = async (e) => { 
                //aquí enviaré el formulario cuando pueda mostrar el dato dentro del input
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("ID TIPO", id_tipo, );//se muestra bien
            };

            return (
                <>
                <form onSubmit={establecerDatos}>
                    ID:{id_tipo} //me muestra esto en pantalla correctamente
                    <input
                    type="text"
                    name="id_tipo"
                    value={id_tipo} //pero el input me aparece vacío <---------------
                    className="form-control"
                    onChange={onChangeInput}
                    />
                    <button className="btn" type="submit">
                    Save
                    </button>
                </form>
                </>
            );
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Probaste seteando value con `formValues.id_tipo`? Lo que pasa es que los values en componentes controlados en React sirven para ir obteniendo los valores ingresados en dicho input a través del hook useState, pero tú al especificar sólo id_tipo en el value, estás referenciando a la declaración de una variable que se obtiene DESDE el state, cosa que no es lo mismo que obtenerlo directamente desde el hook.

Comment: @rafa_pe , ¿Lograste avanzar? saludos